# Undefinded error

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

route.js

```
router.get('/restful', function(req, res){
  console.log("before");
  User.show_deatils(req, res, function(err, resultArray){
   if(!err) {
     req.session.resultArray=resultArray;
    }
  });
  console.log(req.session.resultArray);
  res.render('restful',{resultArray:req.session.resultArray});
});
```

I don't know why I am getting as `undefined` when I am doing it `console.log()` in the above position.If I do `console.log()` just after the `req.session.resultArray=resultArray` then we are getting the result array.

I want to display this `resultArray` in my `view.ejs`. Can anyone suggest me how to solve it.What is the thing I am missing it out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

The console.log runs before the async function actually gets the details from the database. so you get undefined.
Do the render inside the callback. i.e, after you assign result array to session.

```
router.get('/restful', (req, res, next) {
      User.show_deatils(req, res, function(err, resultArray) {
          if(!err) {
              req.session.resultArray=resultArray;
              return res.render('restful' {resultArray:req.session.resultArray}));
           }
       });
});
```

Comment: This does not allow the page to load if I assign it after session

Comment: did you try ?.What do you mean by after session. The basic idea here is, when you enter the page, server gets the details from the database and  then, the `resultArray` would be assigned to `req.session` variable and only after that, the function actually returns by rendering the page with the resultArray.

Comment: I dont know why This is not allowing to load the page.                                     
router.get('/restful', function(req, res){
console.log("before");
  User.show_deatils(req, res, function(err, resultArray){
   if(!err) {
   
    req.session.resultArray=resultArray;
    console.log(req.session.resultArray);


   }
  });
    
res.render('restful',{resultArray:req.session.resultArray});
    

 });
    

This is allowing to navigate to the restful page.But the value of resultArray is becoming "undefined". Where I am doing the mistake?Cant able to find it out.

Comment: When I used req.session.save().The data is been fetched now.But on the view page.The data is not been loaded at the first navigation.Wen we load again the page the data is been loaded.How to fix the issue.Anyone  help me out.

Comment: @riza place the render function just right after you do save() inside the callback. (User.show*)

Answer (score 0):

Just do like this

```
    router.get('/restful', function(req, res){
           console.log("before");
          User.show_deatils(req, res, function(err, resultArray){
           if(!err) { 

             res.render('restful',{resultArray:resultArray});
           }
          });
       });
```

I think this is what you want.

Comment: I have tried dis out.Its not navigating to restful webpage itself.